# Since when does Community vote?

Tags: discussion, votes

Somehow the user named [Community](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/-1/Community) managed to [close a question as a duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/245657/52934) yesterday. Community's vote to close was only the second such on that question. It looked weird to me - it doesn't jive. Community is supposed to be a bot, right? What is it doing voting at all? Does it have any other similarly dubious and sinister abilities of which I can be made aware?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/270345

Answer (score 19, accepted):

SE [have implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes) a new button that lets you close your own question:

[image]

In the specific question you linked to, what happened was that @muru cast a close vote, and this made the following appear to the OP:

[image]

The OP saw it and agreed, so clicked on the button and, as a result, the question was closed and the OP's binding close vote is shown as originating from the Community user.

Don't worry, we still control the AIs, the bot is not on a <del>killing</del> voting spree.

Comment: Wouldn't it be less confusing if the binding close vote was attributed to the OP -- even it the OP may not usually be able to vote to close?